# Restrict access by Store View

Tags: store-view, access

Can you help me please with setting storeview, because I have two storeview: Privat and Clients, I need for storeview Privat entrance access through a password, how to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've build a small extension that might help. You can get it on [Github](https://github.com/sandermangel/rkstorelogin).

It works with an observer on the `controller_action_predispatch` event that will check if there is a customer session, if not it redirects to the login page.

It can be enabled and disabled by storeview

Comment: https://github.com/sandermangel/rkstorelogin - when i istall module in magento 1.7.0.2 - site more not working((

Comment: Can you give a little more information? What kind of error for example

Comment: @JohnGenry looks like you also need to install https://github.com/sandermangel/rkextbase

Comment: Github link is broken